# Cannot resolve keyword '_icontains' into field

Tags: django-models

For a search function in my Django application, I'm using the following statement to query the database for fields containing a search term:

```
search_results = Post.objects.filter(name_icontains=search_term)
```

However, I get this error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'name_icontains' into field. Choices are: content, date, id, name, url, views
```

These are the contents of the models.py file for reference:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=5, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'm following the method for searching exactly as it's described in the documentation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing it with double underscore:

```py
search_results = Post.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_term)
___________________________________________^
```

See [the docs for field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) in Django for more detailed information about `icontains` and other filters.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I missed that.